# how to select all student who takes at least two classes from Peterson but takes only one course from david?

Tags: mysql, xampp

Hi I'm taking MySQL course and I'm stuck on one question, this is my table

```
 Student(S_ID, S_FIRST_NAME, S_LAST_NAME, S_MAJOR)

 Course(C_ID, C_NAME, C_INST_NAME, C_ROOM)
 takes(S_ID,C_ID)
```

and my question is, how to  Find names of all students who takes at least two 
     course taught by Peterson but take only one course from Davidson.

I was able to get the result of student who takes at least 2 course with 
     Peterson with following query:

```
 select student.S_FIRST_NAME from student  inner join
 student_course on student_course.S_ID = student.S_ID 
 -> inner join course on course.C_ID = student_course.C_ID 
 -> where course.C_INST_NAME = 'Peterson' 
 -> group by student.S_FIRST_NAME
 -> having count(distinct course.C_ID)>=2;

 +--------------+
 | S_FIRST_NAME |
 +--------------+
 | Eden         |
 | Kery         |
 | Micheal      |
 | Yeison       |
 +--------------+
```

and i tried following query to meet both requirements:

```
  select student.S_FIRST_NAME from student  inner join student_course on 
  student_course.S_ID = student.S_ID inner join course on course.C_ID =
  student_course.C_ID  where course.C_INST_NAME = 'Peterson'  group by 
  student.S_FIRST_NAME having count(distinct course.C_ID)>=2 and 
  student.S_FIRST_NAME from student inner join student_course on 
  student_course.S_ID = student.S_ID  inner join course on course.C_ID = 
  student_course.C_ID where course.C_INST_NAME = 'Davidson' group by 
  student.S_FIRST_NAME having count(distinct course.C_ID)=1;
```

but didn't work got this error:

```
 ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual 
 that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use 
 near 'from student
 inner join student_course on student_course.S_ID = student.S_ID 
 in' at line 1
 I went back and look at the code again but couldn't figure it out what the 
 problem is, and inner join is the complicated one i think it is just for me. 
 any help would be appreciated please !! thank you in advance.
```

Answer (score 1):

The basic strategy of this answer is to aggregate over the `Course` table by student, and retain only those students having at least two courses at Peterson and at most one course at Davidson.

```
SELECT s.S_FIRST_NAME,
       s.S_LAST_NAME
FROM Student s
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT t.S_ID
    FROM takes t
    INNER JOIN Course c
        ON t.C_ID = c.C_ID
    GROUP BY t.S_ID
    HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN c.C_INST_NAME = 'Peterson' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) >= 2 AND
           SUM(CASE WHEN c.C_INST_NAME = 'Davidson' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) <= 1
) t
    ON s.S_ID = t.S_ID
```

Comment: sorry for bothering you but what that error means i found nothing wrong but got this error:ERROR 1064 (42000):                                                             You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN c.C_INST_NAME = 'Davidson' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) <= 1
) t
    ' at line 12

Comment: @anonymous Sorry, I erroneously included the `HAVING` keyword twice.  Remove the second one as I have done in my updated query.

Comment: @anonymous if this answer is helpful, upvote it. If it answers your question, accept it. That's how this site works.

Comment: so, if i want to select all the student who takes all classes from Davidson, (just modified your code)select s.S_ID from student s inner join (select t.S_ID from takes t inner join course c on t.C_ID = c.C_ID group by t.S_ID having sum(case when c.C_INST_NAME ='Davidson' then 1 else 0 end)=3) t on s.S_ID = t.S_ID;  works since i already know how many classes Davidson teach (in this case 3), if i don't know the classes he is teaching how can i write the query thank you!

Comment: You should open a new question, you are asking something different.